# Insert text at end of Word Section _VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following code which generates a list of appendices based on the first paragraph of each section (skipping section 1), adds this to a string and then inserts that string at the end of section 1.  However for some reason (that I can't figure out) it inserts the appendixList at the beginning of section 2, not end of section 1.  There is a page break next section, at the end of section 1.

```
Sub GenerateAppendixList()
    Dim mainDoc As Document
    Dim appendixSection As section
    Dim appendixParagraph As Paragraph
    Dim appendixList As String
    Dim appendixCount As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    
 
    ' Set reference to the main document
    Set mainDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set rng = mainDoc.Sections(1).Range

    ' Initialize the appendix count
    appendixCount = 1
 
    ' Loop through sections (excluding the main document)
    For Each appendixSection In mainDoc.Sections
        If appendixSection.Index > 1 Then
            ' Get the first paragraph in the appendix section
            Set appendixParagraph = appendixSection.Range.Paragraphs(1)
            
                appendixList = appendixList & "Appendix " & appendixCount & " - " & appendixParagraph.Range.Text '& vbCrLf
                ' Increment the appendix count
                appendixCount = appendixCount + 1
            'End If
        End If
    Next appendixSection
 
    ' Insert the formatted appendix list at the end of the Section 1
    
    rng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    rng.InsertAfter appendixList
    

End Sub
```

I altered the code to
`rng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart` and that acts as I would expect and put the appendixList at the start of section.  Not sure why `rng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart` doesnt work in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `mainDoc.Sections(1).Range` include the section break. `rng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd` collapses `rng` to the ending position (after section break), it is the beginning position of section 2.
- Change: add a line to move it before the section break

```vb
    rng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    rng.MoveEnd unit:=Word.wdCharacter, Count:=-1
    rng.InsertAfter appendixList
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.MoveEnd method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.moveend?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm157155439)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)